# iOS - Schedule UIAlertController To Be Displayed After View Transitions Finish

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

In my app, I let users to log in to their Pocket app accounts. The Pocket SDK forwards the login process to Safari, and when the user attempts to log in, a view transition occurs to go back to my app.

At the same time, my `UIViewController` receives an `NSNotification` that the login either succeeded or failed, and whenever I attempt to show a `UIAlertController` to show the user whether it succeeded or not, nothing happens and I get the following in my log console:

> Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior

I'm assuming it's because my `UIViewController` is trying to present the `UIAlertController` while my app is still transitioning from Safari to my view.

How do I make sure to display this `UIAlertController` AFTER the view transition ends?

Comment: usually there is a completion block for the transitions, so just call your alert from that block if there is one. If there is non, you can put that alert in the viewDidAppear in your viewController, but make sure to add some flag to check whether the transition was initialized, so you don't show the alert all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you (or UIAlertController) is accessing the `.view` property of the view controller at an inappropriate time. Accessing `.view` implicitly triggers `loadView` (and then `viewDidLoad`) automatically when the view is not loaded (see `isViewLoaded`).

You have a lot of options here.

The easiest is probably to add a property to the view controller to flag whether the alert needs to be displayed. When you observe the notification, set the flag to YES. Then, in `-viewDidAppear:` you can check the flag, show the alert and flip the flag to NO.

You could also add a "short circuit" check at the point where the notification is received, like:

```
if (self.isViewLoaded) {
    // show alert now
} else {
    self.needsShowAlert = YES;
}
```